# My script doesn't work as expected

Tags: php

This is the button

```php
<a href="index.php?p=contact">contact<a>
```

This is the php script:

```php
<?php
$p = isset($_GET['p']);

if($p == "artist")
{
    include 'artist.php';   
}

if($p == "contact")
{
    include 'contact.php';  
}

if($p == "releases")
{
    include 'releases.php'; 
}

if($p == "downloads")
{
    include 'downloads.php';    
}

else
{
    include 'home.php'; 
}
?>
```

So my script should include `contact.php` when I hit the button, but instead of including only `contact.php` it includes all php files. (this happens also with the other buttons).

Comment: `$p = isset($_GET['p'])` is going to be true or false you want it to be `if (isset($_GET['p'])) { $p = $_GET['p']; }`

Comment: `$p = isset($_GET['p']);`

You do realise that isset() returns a Boolean value, that you're then assigning to $p

Comment: Next please describe in your title what is going wrong. 'my script isn't working' does not really describe what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: Also, look into `switch` http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now your `$p` variable equals `true` (this is what [isset](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) returns).

Change `$p = isset($_GET['p']);` to `$p = $_GET['p'];` and you'll be good

Even better:

`$p = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : false;`

in this case you're secured against `p` being null

**EDIT:**

There is also another issue with your code - last `else` statement. It is always true when `$p` is different than `downloads`. So either you change every `if` to `else if` like this:

```php
if($p == 'artist')
{
    include 'artist.php';   
}

else if($p == 'contact')
{
    include 'contact.php';  
}
(...)
else
{
    include 'home.php'; 
}
```

or change this to `switch` statement:

```php
switch($p)
{
case 'artist':
    include 'artist.php';
    break;
(...)
default:
    include 'home.php';
}
```

Comment: Good unless `$_GET['p'];` isn't defined: an `isset()` test to see if it's defined and provide a default if not is better

Comment: if i don't use isset i get 
Notice: Undefined index: p in G:\workstation\epnewest\data\localweb\bi_website\index.php on line 7

Comment: check my edit : ``$p = isset($_GET['p']) ? $_GET['p'] : false``

Answer (score 1):

isset($_GET['p']) returns true or false, so the code comparing $p to some strings will always return true and run the code inside the if block.

Change ***$p = isset($_GET['p'])*** simply to ***$p = $_GET['p']***

Answer (score 0):

To make this (more) reusable, you should alter your script a bit. Create a simple whitelist, check it the parameter is allowed, and if yes, include the $_GET['p']'s value directly:

```
$allowed = false;

if (isset($_GET['p'])) 

{

switch $_GET['p'] {

  case 'contact':
     $allowed = true;
     break;

  case 'artist':
     $allowed = true;
     break;

   // and so on for all your IFs

}

  if ($allowed === true) {
    include $_GET['p'].'.php'
  }
  else 
  {
    die('illegal parameter found')
  }
}
```